# How to bind images from JSON image path in the viewholder?

Tags: android, json, kotlin

I am getting the base url and the poster path from tmdb JSON API.  I'm trying to take the image path (which is a URL path like this `/986qw1312312e03ituwp.jpg"`), add it to the base URL with simple string concatenation, get the image and use it in my `onBindViewHolder` method:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: PosterHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.view?.movie_poster?.setImageResource()
        holder.view?.movie_poster?.scaleType = ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER
    }
```

What is the best way to do this?  If I create a separate method or class with ImageLoader or Picasso, how do I then use the image returned in the `.setImageResource()` method?

I'm trying to learn Android development with Kotlin and this is a project I chose to build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way to handle all Image loading is to use image cache libraries,
You have multiple options like glide, Picasso , UIL.

In your adapter just pass json passed list , and on your onBindViewHolder just load all images with your string concatenation Url.

Simple example with glide

```
GlideApp.with(context)
    .load(URL)
    .into(imageView)
```

Comment: That explanation does not help at all.  Could you demonstrate?